# Firebase: .priority value

Tags: firebase

- How do I check the .priority values are in my "Forge"?
- According to docs, smaller .priority value comes before larger .priority value. If I use seconds since epoch for priority, and I want the latest children to show up on top, should I set .priority to be 1/seconds?

> Children with a number as their priority come next. They are sorted numerically by priority (small to large) and then lexicographically by name (a to z).

- From experimentation, I've determined that if I set .priority to java.util.Date#getTime, oldest children show up on top in my Forge, but latest children show up on top in my Javascript on() when ranking using prevChildName. Why is this?

Comment: For descending time use negative priority like `-1 * Date.now()`

Answer (score 5):

You can see `.priority` in a json by "Export JSON" from the Forge.

Answer (score 5):

use

```
snapshot.getPriority();
```

more at 
https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/setwithpriority.html

Answer (score 4):

It's **not available from Forge but** you can see it from the JSON format:

`https://YOURAPP.firebaseio.com/.json?print=pretty&format=export`

Answer (score 2):

There's no way in Forge right now to see the actual priority values, but the children will be sorted correctly.

If what you want is to sort items in reverse-chronological-order, I'd suggest simply setting the priority to a normal timestamp (or using push -- it orders them automatically). You can then simply render them backwards to achieve the reverse order you want. For example, rather than appending new messages to the bottom of a list in your app, you could insert them before the first element.

Answer (score 0):

`snapshot.exportVal()`

> Exports the entire contents of the DataSnapshot as a Javascript
>   object. This is similar to val(), except priority information is
>   included (if available), making it suitable for backing up your data.
>
> The export format is a Javascript object with ".priority" entries
>   added to any object with a priority. In the case of primitive values
>   (a string, number, or boolean) with a priority, the value is wrapped
>   in an object with ".value" and ".priority" properties. In the case of
>   primitive values without a priority, a primitive value is returned.

Source: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/exportval.html